# Concat two Properties using linq and then convert to comma separated string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of objects (person)

```
public class Person 
    {
        public virtual Guid         PersonID { get; set; }
        public virtual AnotherObj   ABCD     { get; set; }
        public virtual int          IdNum       { get; set; }
        public virtual string       FirstName   { get; set; }
        public virtual string       LastName    { get; set; }                 
    }
```

Then my list:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>
...add a bunch of people....
```

Now I want to get a comma separated string of the people, but I want to manipulate it so that I have `Person.FirstName +" "+ Person.LastName`

I realize I can do this via a foreach. But I have to imagine there is another way where i can still use

```
string.Join(", ",people.Select(x=>...not sure what to do here).ToList())
```

Answer (score 5):

You are already on the right path.

```
string.Join(", ", people.Select(p => $"{p.FirstName} {p.LastName}"));
```

Answer (score 4):

So, where you have your "not sure what to do here" is where you put the logic you want to do for each "iteration" basically.

In your example, you want to have `Person.FirstName +" "+ Person.LastName` as you've already said which is really close to the solution actually!

So, when you're doing a `Select` on your `List<People>` then your `x` parameter will hold the value of a single person you're trying to use.

So let's look at what you have then change it over to how LINQ would understand it.

```
string.Join(", ",people.Select(x=>.ToList(x => Person.FirstName + " " + Person.LastName))

string.Join(", ",people.Select(x=>.ToList(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName))
```

All I did was replace the `Person` with `x`. It's kind of like saying for each person, do the following in this select statement. I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that the result should be:

```
"FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 LastName2, ..."
```

The expression should be:

```
string people = string.Join(",", people.Select(p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a property:

```
public virtual string FullName { get {this.FirstName + " " this.LastName}; }
```

this would do the name concatenating in it.
String.Join becomes:

```
string.Join(", ",people.Select(person=>person.FullName)
```